# Getting ILocalVariable from parsing VariableDeclarationStatement

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i am parsing java source code with Eclipse AST parser and successfully can locate local variable as `VariableDeclarationStatement`. Problem is i need variable as `ILocalVariable` for usage of refactoring. In this case `getJavaElement()` doesn't work since local variables arent in Java Model. Any idea how to get it from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:
Having programmed in hand `VariableDeclarationStatement variable`
You can code as:

```
IVariableBinding binding = variable.resolveBinding();
ILocalVariable local = (ILocalVariable) binding.getJavaElement();
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, but none of the solutions above worked for me. After some research I found a solution, which works for me:

```
// reconcile corresponding compilation unit
compilationUnit.reconcile(ICompilationUnit.NO_AST, false, null, null);

// parse code and get the elements
IJavaElement[] elements =
    ((ICodeAssist) compilationUnit).codeSelect(startPos + length, 0);

// if there is an element and its an instance of ILocalVariable.
if (anElements.length > 0 && anElements[0] instanceof ILocalVariable) {
  return (ILocalVariable) anElements[0];
}
```

So in conclusion: You need the starting position and the length of the variable. (`startPos` + `length`). And the compilation unit, which I already had.

Comment: should it actually be codeSelect(startPos, length), rather than codeSelect(startPos + length) ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that I haven't tried this myself, but looking at the source code, the below mentioned steps should work:

1. Make sure that the ASTParser is created using `setResolveBindings(true)`
2. Get all of the `VariableDeclarationFragments` by calling `VariableDeclarationStatement.fragments()`.
3. For each fragment you are interested in, call `resolveBinding()`.
4. For each binding, you should be able to call `getJavaElement()`.

Comment: already tried this way but unfortunately `getJavaElement()` returns null for local variables

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option.  Create the ILocalVariable object yourself.  The `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.LocalVariable` is internal API (and the constructor has changed between 3.6 and 3.7).

The constructor (in Eclipse 3.6) takes the following arguments:

```
    public LocalVariable(
        JavaElement parent,
        String name,
        int declarationSourceStart,
        int declarationSourceEnd,
        int nameStart,
        int nameEnd,
        String typeSignature,
        org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Annotation[] astAnnotations)
```

Most of these parameters should be fairly straight forward and available directly from the `VariableDeclarationStatement`.  Note that `typeSignature` is not the fully qualified name, but rather the type signatures generated from `org.eclipse.jdt.core.Signature`.

Answer (score 0):

```
IVariableBinding binding = variable.resolveBinding();
if (!binding.isField() && !binding.isEnumConstant() && !binding.isParameter()) 
{
    ILocalVariable local = (ILocalVariable) binding.getJavaElement();
}
```